# Justpy QSelect doesn't display values in dropdown when using filter event

Tags: python, quasar-framework, justpy

I've been trying to create a filtering dropdown menu in Justpy. I've been using a QSelect component to do this. The second dropdown menu [here](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#using-menu-and-filtering) is what I'd like to build.

I'm able to get the dropdown menu to populate and display the values I want using the input event. I can manually select the value I want this way. My issue is when I use the filter event, the dropdown no longer populates. Instead, I get a spinning "loading" icon.

Here is my code:

```
import justpy as jp

dropdown_items = [123, 456, 789]

def filter_event(self, msg):
    # For testing purposes, just update the list of items in the dropdown to what was typed into dropdown
    new_items = [msg.value]
    self.options = new_items

def filter_test(request):
    wp = jp.QuasarPage(dark=True, tailwind=True, title="Filter Test Page")
    d1 = jp.QDiv(text="Select a number", classes="q-pa-md text-xl", style="max-width: 600px", a=wp)

    dropdown = jp.QSelect(label="Test dropdown", options=dropdown_items, multiple=True, use_input=True, clearable=True, use_chips=True, padding=True, bordered=True, a=d1)
    dropdown.on('filter', filter_event)

    return wp

jp.justpy(filter_test)
```

I've tried calling Quasar methods within my event handler, for example: `wp.dropdown.run_method(f'filter({msg.value})', msg.websocket)`, but that didn't change anything. I've experimented with using different events, filling in different props, etc., but I haven't been able to get any closer.

Perhaps I need to add a model to the QSelect component, but I don't really know what that would like like.

I assume I'm missing something very simple. I don't have any experience with JavaScript, so finding solutions has been very difficult. Any tips or guidance that'll get me closer to a solution is greatly appreciated. Thank you.